# Magick.NET-x64 is throwing a "dll not found" exception when deployed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, imagemagick

When I deploy (using web deploy) my asp.net Web API project, I get the following error (see stack trace below)

```
Server Error in '/images.mysite.com' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'Magick.NET-x64.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Magick.NET-x64.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Magick.NET-x64.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +210
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +242
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +17
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +122

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Magick.NET-x64.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +12762790
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +503
   System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +142
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +334
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +203
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +152
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Magick.NET-x64.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12883252
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12724313

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

My server is windows server 2008 r2 standard

Running IIS : Windows server 2008 r2 standard

My project properties are:

- Configuration: Active(Debug)
- Platform:Active(x64)
- Platform target: x64
- warning level: 4
- output pasth: bin\
- treat warnings as errors : none
- generate seriealization assembly: auto

On a side note, when I DO publish he project I’ve noticed that “ImageMagick (Magick.NET-x64)” is not showing up in the package manifest. Strange? What the hell?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EtsTraceLogger" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="4.0.30506" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Any help in the deployment of an Magick.NET-x64 based application would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Need more information ):

Comment: So what are the specifics of the error when you set custom errors to "off"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh...

I fixed this by installing the following,

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Hope that helps!

Comment: Install it on the server - typically the dev env doesn't need it installed because you're already using Visual Studio, but the server doesn't have these necessary libs and throws this obscure exception.

Answer (score 1):

Magick.NET Needs VC 2012 Runtime to be installed. (Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012)

Also once Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 is installed on the server, it requires a restart.